# Django and Pytz what is going wrong?

Tags: django, python-3.x, fastcgi

I'm currently trying to make Django1.6b2 with Python3.3 work on my server.
I got so many problems for now that I just can't list them (Flup, Threading, FastCGI) and finally I'm almost there. Here is my django.fcgi :

```
#!/home/benjamin/Python/3.3/bin/python3

import os, sys
import django
print("Django Version : {}".format(django.VERSION))
print("Python Version : {}".format(sys.version[:3]))

_PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0, _PROJECT_DIR)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(_PROJECT_DIR))

_PROJECT_NAME = _PROJECT_DIR.split('/')[-1]
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "%s.settings" % _PROJECT_NAME

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

And here is my traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "website/public/django.fcgi", line 17, in <module>
    runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
  File "/home/benjamin/Python/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/servers/fastcgi.py", line 143, in runfastcgi
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import get_internal_wsgi_application
  File "/home/benjamin/Python/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 25, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  File "/home/benjamin/Python/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
  File "/home/benjamin/Python/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django import http
  File "/home/benjamin/Python/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.http.response import (HttpResponse, StreamingHttpResponse,
  File "/home/benjamin/Python/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.utils import six, timezone
  File "/home/benjamin/Python/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 11, in <module>
    import pytz
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1567, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1534, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "/home/benjamin/modules/pytz-2013b-py2.6.egg/pytz/__init__.py", line 1103, in <module>
  File "/home/benjamin/modules/pytz-2013b-py2.6.egg/pytz/__init__.py", line 1103, in <listcomp>
  File "/home/benjamin/modules/pytz-2013b-py2.6.egg/pytz/__init__.py", line 107, in resource_exists
  File "/home/benjamin/modules/pytz-2013b-py2.6.egg/pytz/__init__.py", line 100, in open_resource
  File "/nfs/http7/benjamin/Python/distribute-0.7.3/pkg_resources.py", line 949, in resource_stream
    self, resource_name
  File "/nfs/http7/benjamin/Python/distribute-0.7.3/pkg_resources.py", line 1379, in get_resource_stream
    return StringIO(self.get_resource_string(manager, resource_name))
  File "/nfs/http7/benjamin/Python/distribute-0.7.3/pkg_resources.py", line 1956, in StringIO
    return StringIO(*args,**kw)
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes
```

How can I solve that ? It seems that Django tries to import a module that I can't find with pip-3.3 (pytz-2013b-py2.6.egg) it's 2.6 and why does pip install that ? xD

Could someone help me ? =)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug in distribute package for python3 at the following location -

pkg_resources.py -> get_resource_string
this method returns bytes and StringIO is expecting for string.
I tried to decode it by using decode("ISO-8859-1") method then I got error in pytz package.

However I got the workaround for this -

> Change "./pytz-2013.7-py3.3.egg" to "./pytz" in
>   "site-packages/easy-install.pth" file.
>
> Make sure you have unzipped pytz directory in your site-packages
>   directory.